# How to create this layout with a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to create a recycler view with this type of layout. The items are strings and can apear with diferent sizes, i dont know how much items there will be in each row. Can I do this with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager?
The image is just a fake example, there can be more items in each row

[image: description]

Comment: @Andrew Thompson do you know what you are reviewing? you delete my tags, i lose points? and you remove the wrong tags? do you know what is a layout manager in android? do you understand this question to edit it? and you down vote it?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson can you undo the wrong things you did?

Comment: *"do you know what you are reviewing?"* I sure do. the [tag:layout-manager] tag is for (Oracle) Java layouts. Not Android. There is a separate [tag:android-layout] for ..Android layouts. *"can you undo the wrong things you did?"* Can you **read** the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on your question?

Comment: ok, thank you very much, you're the best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might wanna check out the open-source [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout), developed by Google, especially [`FlexboxLayoutManager`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/RecyclerView.md) which is a layout manager for a `RecyclerView`.

To create the layout manager with the right config, just do this:

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager();
layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
```

For more information, check out the Android Developers Blog's [post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html).

Comment: thanks :) i didnt knew that layout manager, I will try it and will put your awnser as correct if it works